# Read integers separated by commas from Text file in VB.NET Console Application

Tags: arrays, vb.net, console, integer

I have to write a VB.NET Console Application in Visual Studio which will read Integers from a Text (.txt) file and put them into an Array.

So far I have tried this:

```
    Dim arr(100) As Integer
    Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader("Data.txt")

    For j As Integer = 0 To 100 - 1
        arr(j) = Integer.Parse(stream_reader.ReadLine())

    Next j

    stream_reader.Close()
    Console.ReadLine()
```

But as soon as I run the program it throws an exception with the message:

> "FormatException was unhandled."

Contents of the text file (Data.txt) are in this format :-

```
11,6,7,1,2,5,4,3,9,8,0
```

Comment: Sounds like a runtime error, and means that the contents of one (or more, but it will stop at the first one) of the lines in not a valid number.  Check out the docs for [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integers are separated by commas, the StreamReader would be of no use. You can use the `String.Split()` method like this:

```
Dim arr(100) As Integer
Dim temp = File.ReadAllText("Data.txt").Split(","C)
For j As Integer = 0 To 100 - 1
    arr(j) = Integer.Parse(temp(j))
Next j
```

**Note** - If you specify `100 - 1` in the For Loop, you will need to ensure that the text file contains 100 integers. Otherwise, you can first evaluate `Dim temp = File.ReadAllText("Data.txt").Split(","C)` and then use the `temp.Length - 1` in both the loop and as the capacity of the array.

Comment: It's giving me that error now, never used that before..

"Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'Integer'"

Comment: it's throwing me now a "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled"

Is it, because you are using `temp` as array in the `for loop` but didn't declare it as one?

Comment: Does your text file have 100 items? If it is variable then change 100 - 1 to temp.Length - 1

Comment: It's compiling now, the Output gives me the numbers but also a bunch of "0"